# Who is systemd-coredump and why is he on my system?

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a rsync that has the following configuration:

```
rsync -aur4zvq --force /root/folder/on/local/ root@remote:/root/folder/somewhere/on/remote
```

This is run by a crontab as root for security reasons and it is supposed to place the files on remote also with root rights.

The crontab works without any warnings or errors, and the files are placed to the right folder, but for my surprise the files on remote somehow now belong to the user `systemd-coredump` and not to root

In the past it worked perfect ... what happened?

My crontab looks like this

```
* * * * * rsync -aur4zvq --force /root/folder/on/local/ root@remote:/root/folder/somewhere/on/remote
```

Is it better to do this with a rsync daemon? I never used rsync with a daemon.

How do I need to configure this using a daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It could be that Rsync is setting there remote user ID to the same user ID as `systemd-coredump`.

Meaning that if `systemd-coredump` has a user ID of 2 and the files on your local system are owned by you `max_muster` with the user ID of 2, when the files are transferred over, the “2” is interpreted as  `systemd-coredump`.

You can check this yourself on your system by checking your user ID value in `/etc/passwd` and then comparing who has the same user ID value on the remote system in that `/etc/passwd`.

To force Rsync to change user ownership on the remote machine, modify your command to add a `chmod` option like this:

```
rsync --chown=USER:GROUP -aur4zvq --force /root/folder/on/local/ root@remote:/root/folder/somewhere/on/remote
```

And change that `USER:GROUP` to `root:root` like this:

```
rsync --chown=root:root -aur4zvq --force /root/folder/on/local/ root@remote:/root/folder/somewhere/on/remote
```

Just note that the `--chown=USER:GROUP` option works on Rsync version 3.1.0 and higher.

Comment: I think I also must skip `-p` as it seems to be the one who preserves the uid, and p is in `-a`

Comment: @MaxMuster Makes sense. Try it out and see what happens; using the command with `--dry-run` can’t hurt also. That will show you exactly what Rsync will do without actually doing it; aka: a dry run.

Comment: dry run does not show the chmod and chown modifications it shows only what files are selected

Answer (score 0):

The problem is also the `-a` as it equals to `-rlptgoD`

```
   --recursive, -r          recurse into directories
   --links, -l              copy symlinks as symlinks
          --safe-links      ignore symlinks that point outside the tree       
   --perms, -p              preserve permissions
   --times, -t              preserve modification times
   --group, -g              preserve group
   --owner, -o              preserve owner (super-user only)
   -D                       same as --devices --specials
```

Since it preserves the UID.

So preserving of user and group permissions should be made as [@Giacomo1968 shows in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/1699099/167207) with `--chown` not with `-a`

There could be also another solution using  `-e "ssh -l ssh-user"` but I have not tested it.

Comment: It's a wonderful thing that you can't correct comments as well. It would be nice if this fribach with the correction of foreign contributions would stop. But it is part of the "Cancel Culture" and is getting worse by the day.

Comment: Editing is a part of the Stack Exchange culture and allows us to ensure high quality questions and answers. It has nothing to do with your so-called "cancel culture". Please read [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://superuser.com/help/editing) As stated there " If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."